# Â Symbol Appears when I type £

Tags: html

I'm getting this odd symbol `Â` each time I write the symbol `£`.

I read somthing about `UTF - 8` but I have no idea what that is.

Any fixes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What region are you in and what is your keyboard type?  I get this issue in Linux when the OS is set to GB region

Comment: Using windows in UK region and I assume my keyboard is set to UK

Comment: Does it only happen when typing in web pages?

Comment: Yes it only happens when I am trying to put prices on a webpage

Comment: I have seen people report experiencing this type of thing after downloading fonts, although this probably isnt specific to web pages.  In your web browser is it set to en-GB/English? Oh and is this occuring only at one web page or all?

Comment: To quickly switch between keyboard (language) layouts, press WinKey+Space. I suppose you accidentally did that. Btw, this question isn't related to programming; it should probably be over at [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/).